# Create new pd dataframe column that gives a date based on day and week starting data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe that has two columns, the first column is 'Week Starting' and the other is 'Day'. I wanna create a new column that uses the data from the other two columns to give a full date. For example, from the table below, the first entry of the new column should be 5/04/2021 and the second should be should 6/04/2021.

| Week Starting | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 5/04/2021 | Monday |
| 5/04/2021 | Tuesday |
| 5/04/2021 | Wednesday |

I've tried the follwing the solution but i get and error

```
g['Week Starting'] = pd.to_datetime(g['Week Starting'])

conditions = [ (g['Day'] == 'Monday'), (g['Day'] == 'Tuesay'), (g['Day'] == 
                'Wednesday')]

values = [g['Week Starting'],(g['Week Starting'] + timedelta(days=1)), 
          (g['Week Starting'] + timedelta(days=2))]

g['Date'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

ERROR:

The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[uint8]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be the simplest solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"week_starting":["04/05/2021","04/05/2021","04/05/2021"],
                    "day":["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]})

df['week_starting'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week_starting'])

conditions = {"Monday":0,"Tuesday":1,"Wednesday":2}

df["date"] = df.apply(lambda x:x['week_starting']+pd.Timedelta(conditions[x["day"]],"day"),axis=1)
```

You add the timedelta to each date using the apply method.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with mapping values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['week_starting'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week_starting'])

d = {"Monday":0,"Tuesday":1,"Wednesday":2,
     "Thursday":3,"Friday":4,"Saturday":5, 'Sunday':6}

df["date"] = df['week_starting'] + pd.to_timedelta(df["day"].map(d),"day")
print (df)
  week_starting        day       date
0    2021-04-05     Monday 2021-04-05
1    2021-04-05    Tuesday 2021-04-06
2    2021-04-05  Wednesday 2021-04-07
```

Comment: This works too. I like it better since it's simpler and no lamdas are involved. Thanks.

Comment: @runraver - Yes, it is faster and better, so why is accepting another solution?